# When declaring constants within models, do I need to wrap them within a class?

Tags: python, import, module

Assume I have a module called "instrument.py"
in this module there is a class "Guitar"
I can import it like this:

```
from instrument import Guitar
```

and instantiate the object:

```
guitar = Guitar()
```

also I want to import "type" of the "instrument"

```
from instrument import gtype
```

I want to access the type of the instrument by writting:

```
type1 = gtype.ACCUSTIC
type2 = gtype.BASS
```

Do "gtype" also have to be a class (gtype) inside the module, if I want to access it like described above?

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `gtype` is a class within `instrument` with the fields `BASS` and so on.

Like this:

```
class gtype:
    BASS = 10
    ACOUSTIC = 20
```

Etc...

More info:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html